# Angular Lazy Loading on App-Routing.module.ts loading default pages

Tags: angular, routes, angular9

I have a web app running at Angular 9 and ASP.NET core v2.2, and I have these Routes at `app-routing.module.ts`,

```
    const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./layouts/website-layout/website-layout.module').then(mod => mod.WebsiteLayoutModule),
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        loadChildren: () => import('./error-page/error-page.module').then(mod => mod.AppErrorPageModule)
    }
];
```

The `website-layout-routing.module.ts` contains many children routes. For example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: WebsiteLayoutComponent,
        children: [
                {
                path: WebSitePagesRoutes.LegaL.TermsOfUsePage,
                loadChildren: () => import('../../website-pages/terms-of-use/terms-of-use.module').then(mod => mod.TermsOfUseModule)
            },
            {
                path: WebSitePagesRoutes.LegaL.PrivacyPolicyPage,
                loadChildren: () => import('../../website-pages/privacy-policy/privacy-policy.module').then(mod => mod.PrivacyPolicyModule)
            },
        ]
```

The `website-layout.component.html` contains this code:

```
<div class="app-container">
    <app-navbar>
        <div class="app-content-wrapper"
            <main>
                <router-outlet></router-outlet>
            </main>
            <footer>
                <app-footer></app-footer>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </app-navbar>
</div>
```

And each children loaded at `website-layout-routing.module.ts` contains the minimal routing configuration possible. For example:

```
routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: TermsOfUsePageComponent
    }
];
```

When I enter a page, for example the main page of the web app, the `website-layout-routing.module.ts` loads with a number of .js files with a prefix of `default~`, as in the following image:

[image]

I believe this is the default page of any module found under `website-layout.module.ts`.
It seems that in my case, the `app-routing.module.ts` loads all the default pages that are under `website-layout-routing.module.ts`, even though I'm not on those pages. Here's a callstack for each `default~` .js shown in the previous screenshot.

[image]

How can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the code snippets correctly, I would expect that all route components and associated files referenced by `WebsiteLayoutModule` would be loaded when that module is lazy loaded. It will always load straight off as it's the empty url component in AppRoutingModule

If you also want the child route components to be lazy loaded you'll need to extract them to their own modules and repeat the lazy loading process - although I would suggest setting up a minimal demo to test

Comment: We have the same situation, we already doing what you're suggesting, and it behaves the same.